# How to get column value from C# Expression Func

Tags: c#, lambda, func

My EF model looks like this:

```
public partial class SalesPipelineEntryClosedInformation : FoxHireEntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClosedDetails { get; set; }
    public bool Won { get; set; }
    public int? TypeCompetitorId { get; set; }
    public int? TypeLostReasonId { get; set; }
    public int? TypeDeclineReasonId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TypeCompetitorId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(TypeCompetitor.SalesPipelineEntryClosedInformations))]
    public virtual TypeCompetitor Competitor { get => Get(_competitor); set => _competitor = value; }
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(TypeLostReasonId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(TypeLostReason.SalesPipelineEntryClosedInformations))]
    public virtual TypeLostReason LostReason { get => Get(_lostReason); set => _lostReason = value; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TypeDeclineReasonId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(TypeDeclineReason.SalesPipelineEntryClosedInformations))]
    public virtual TypeDeclineReason DeclineReason { get => Get(_declineReason); set => _declineReason = value; }
}
```

I have a method that updates stats based on which property of the entity changed. It looks like this:

```
private async Task CalculateStats(InsightType insightType)
{
    if (insightType.Value == InsightType.Competitor.Value)
    {
        await processStatsList(x => x.TypeCompetitorId.HasValue, x => x.Competitor.Name, new List<string> {"Competitor"}, InsightType.Competitor);
    }
    else if (insightType.Value == InsightType.IndustryReason)
    {
        await processStatsList(x => x.TypeDeclineReasonId.HasValue, x => x.DeclineReason.Name, new List<string> {"DeclineReason"}, InsightType.IndustryReason);
    }
    else if (insightType.Value == InsightType.LostReason)
    {
        await processStatsList(x => x.TypeLostReasonId.HasValue, x => x.LostReason.Name, new List<string> {"LostReason"}, InsightType.LostReason);
    }
}
```

And the `processStatsList` method is:

```
private async Task processStatsList(Expression<Func<SalesPipelineEntryClosedInformation, bool>> whereClause, 
                                    Expression<Func<SalesPipelineEntryClosedInformation, string>> relatedTableNameValue, 
                                    List<string> includes, InsightType insightType)
{
    await clearRecordTypes(insightType.Value);
    var closedInfo = await _genericRepository.GetList(whereClause, includes);

    var stats = closedInfo.Select(x => new
        {
            x.TypePipelineDealTypeId,
            relatedTableNameValue.Value
        }).GroupBy(x => new {x.Name})
        .Select(x => new SalesInsightStat
        {
            Count = x.Count(),
            Name = x.Key.Name,
            InsightTypeId = insightType.Value
        }).ToList();

    await _genericRepository.AddRangeAsync(stats);
}
```

I'm not sure how to set up the second expression, `relatedTableNameValue`, to output the actual value of the Name column.  All three tables have the same Name column, so I'm just trying to get the value of that column.  Obviously, `relatedTableNameValue.Value` doesn't work, but I'm not sure how to get that value.

Comment: You can try looking into [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) and doing something like `.AsExpandable().Select(x => {..., Name = relatedTableNameValue.Compile()(x)})`.

Comment: Ah geeze, I was so close.  At one point I tried the .Compile() but didn't realize I needed to follow it with (x).  That works great.  Thanks!

Comment: What is return type of `_genericRepository.GetList`? If it is `IEnumerable` - what is the point of `Expression` for `relatedTableNameValue`?

Comment: Yes it is an `IEnumerable`.  The point of relatedTableNameValue is that I'm getting a list of SalesPipelineEntryClosedInformation entities which each have a TypeCompetitor or TypeLostReason related table entry, which has a Name column, and the idea was that I could get the Name value of any of those related tables with the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `closedInfo` is `IEnumerable` you can just compile the expression and invoke it:

```
var stats = closedInfo
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.TypePipelineDealTypeId,
        relatedTableNameValue.Compile()(x)
    })
    .GroupBy(x => new {x.Name})
```

But since `relatedTableNameValue` is not used with `IQueryable`'s  I would recommend to just change the parameter to be a `Func`:

```
private async Task processStatsList(Expression<Func<SalesPipelineEntryClosedInformation, bool>> whereClause,
    Func<SalesPipelineEntryClosedInformation, string> relatedTableNameValue,
     List<string> includes, 
     InsightType insightType)
{
    // ...
    var stats = closedInfo
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.TypePipelineDealTypeId,
            relatedTableNameValue(x)
        })
        .GroupBy(x => new {x.Name})

    // ...
}
```